# Acessing CONIN$ without a tty

Tags: windows, cmd, libuv

I am trying to get access to a file descriptor which receives input from the console. I am currently using

```
HANDLE fd = CreateFile(
    "CONIN$",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    TRUE,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    0);
SetConsoleMode(fd, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT);
```

And returning the fd to a program that reads (based on libuv) the input from the console.

This works fine when the process is executed in the console, but reading from the fd crashes when I pipe input into the program

```
echo hello | inputProgram
```

I have a suspicion that there is no console associated with the input process, but I'm not certain. How do I properly read the input into the cmd window when executing in this way?

---

So I a am binding to this C++ program in Node.js. I call

```
var ReadStream = require("tty").ReadStream();
var TTY = process.binding("tty_wrap").TTY;

module.exports = function () {
    var opentty = require("./bin/opentty.node") // program returns the fd int
    var fd = opentty();
    var t = new _TTY(fd, true);
    return new ReadStream(t);
}
```

opentty returns 3 in redirected input mode for the file handle. The code that deals with this file handle can be found here

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/tty_wrap.cc#L185

which essentially calls into `uv_tty_init` found here

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/tty.c#L99

The stream errors with `Error: read EBADF`, syscall: read

Comment: If you don't have one, one should be created for you.  Is `inputProgram` a console application?  Does `CreateFile` fail, and if so, what error code is returned?  If not, what exactly goes wrong and when?

Comment: if it helps, inputProgram is a node.js process, which should be a console application if I understand what that means correctly. CreateFile does not fail, but passing the file handle off to libuv to create a readstream from the file handle causes the application to just exit, probably segfault. My suspicion is that the console input does not refer to that of the parent cmd window.

Comment: You should inherit the parent's console.  What happens if you simply issue a `ReadFile` against the handle?  I fear the actual problem is embedded deeply in libuv, which I'm not familiar with - do you have the source code?  Are you able to run it in a debugger so as to see where the actual failure is?

Comment: https://github.com/Matt-Esch/opentty/blob/master/win32/opentty.cc if I check the pipe type, it comes back as UNKNOWN. type check is here https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/handle.c#L56 - There are some additional options in createfile that might be the problem, inherit rings a bell.

Comment: I note that the code in `opentty.cc` doesn't check whether the call to `CreateFile` succeeds or not?

Comment: Also it's not clear to me how you're converting the HANDLE into a uv_file object; are you sure the HANDLE is getting through to uv_guess_handle intact?  Also note that if this is a 64-bit process, you may be truncating the HANDLE by casting it to int32_t (certain handles are guaranteed to have only 32 significant bits, but I don't think a console handle is one of them).

Comment: FWIW, your CreateFile call works fine for me, even if input is piped to the program; and GetFileType returns FILE_TYPE_CHAR as expected.

Comment: Hmm interesting that you say that. I am fairly sure the integer is coming back fine. The call works for me, and the handle is returned. Asking libuv what type of stream it is though, I get UNKNOWN.

Comment: Can you show the code that turns the handle into a uv_file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50084/discussion-between-matt-esch-and-harry-johnston)

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the Node repository it seems clear that `new _TTY(fd, true)` is expecting a C file descriptor, but you're passing it a Win32 handle.

The [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) function creates a file descriptor from a handle.

So, you should try

```
var t = new _TTY(_open_osfhandle(fd), true);
```

(as discussed in the comments, this will only work if you're sharing the C runtime with libuv.)

Ideally you would use libuv's open function, but unfortunately there's a bug in [fs__open](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26-release/deps/uv/src/win/fs.c#L397):

```
  case _O_RDWR:
    access = FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
```

This is where it decides which access permissions to request.  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE and FILE_GENERIC_READ are, as the names suggest, specific to files, and can't be used to open CONIN$.  It should be

```
  case _O_RDWR:
    access = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
```

which will work for both files and other types of objects such as the console input and output.  (I've reproduced this in a simple C program; on my system, using the FILE_* permissions definitely prevents you from opening CONIN$.)

Comment: I tried this. The C file descriptor is the same as the handle in this scenario, i.e. the HANDLE is 3 and returning _open_osfhandle(fd, _O_RDWR) also returns 3.

Comment: The fact that the numbers are the same is a coincidence - not a particularly strange one, mind, as they both count up from 0.  All it means is that at that point in the code you have the same number of handles as you have file descriptors.

Comment: ... or possibly not, something a bit odd does seem to be happening with the Win32 handles; perhaps something to do with how cmd.exe sets up the inherited handles, or to how console mode applications are initialized, I'm not sure.

Comment: To follow up, for the record, based on the discussion in chat: I suspect that this doesn't work because the libuv code isn't sharing the same runtime library instance as the OPs code, so the file descriptor generated in one isn't valid in the other.  However, it's not entirely clear.

Comment: That should have said, calling into libuv with `uv_fs_open` also fails to open CONIN$